# Setting up Cube Map

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, lwjgl

Here is the code I am trying to use to set up a Cube Map in LWJGL.

```
public static int setUpCubeMap(String filename, int anisotropyLevel, boolean clamp,   boolean pixelated, boolean mipmapped) {
    IntBuffer tmp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    glGenTextures(tmp);
    tmp.rewind();
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
        decoder.decode(buf, decoder.getWidth() * 4, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
        buf.flip();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, tmp.get(0));
        org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBTextureStorage.glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, (int)(Math.log(Math.max(decoder.getHeight(), decoder.getWidth()))/Math.log(2))+1, GL_RGBA8, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight());
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0, 0, 0, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

        if(mipmapped)
            org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

        if(clamp) {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        } else {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T);
        }

        if(pixelated) {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        } else {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        }

        if(mipmapped)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        else
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        if(anisotropyLevel > 1)
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, anisotropyLevel);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        System.out.println("Loaded texture successfully from: " + filename + " with dimensions of " + decoder.getWidth() + "x" + decoder.getHeight());

    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error " + filename + " not found");
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error decoding " + filename);
    }
    tmp.rewind();
    return tmp.get(0);
}
```

I then pass the texture to a `samplerCube` in a shader and call `textureCube()` to display it. Sadly, the screen shows up black, and when I call `glGetError()` I get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` and `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For debugging call glGetError after EVERY OpenGL command. This gets you the line and command which issues the error. Please post the exact line producing the error or go to [link](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/). There is for every command a list of possible errors and their conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems, none of these definitely prevent the code from working, I list them anyway.

The glTexSubImage2D call at the beginning is is superfluous.

- calling it with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP causes an error [glTexSubImage2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml).
- you are filling in the data the correct way down below

Also related to this, the call to glGenerateMipmap should happen after those other six glTexSubImage2D calls.

And in this section, in the else clause, the third parameter to both function calls is wrong.

```
if(clamp) {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
} else {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T);
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problems you mentioned, and called `glGetError()` every line. I learned that all my `glTexImage2D()` calls are giving me `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Nothing else has any problems.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I was stupid. I bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`. Sorry about that :P

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use gDEBugger; it gives a very understandable description of the problem and exactly when it occurs.